# Retrieve short_name in formatted address received from the google geocoding api V3

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I am using Google geocoding API V3 to geocode addresses. Formatted Address returned from then geocode service contains long name like NortEast. I want short name in the FormattedAddress field like NE. Returned json does contain address parts which have both Long name and short name but the formattedAddress field only contains long names. I don't want to concatenate the address parts to create a complete address. Rather I want google to return me the short names in the FormattedAddress field. 
How can I tell google api to return me the short names instead of long names in formattedaddress field.

Thanx